# Mercurial - Merge parent changes into child fork as individual commits?

Tags: mercurial, merge, fork

My desire is to keep my fork up to date with the parent, and ideally record the parent's individual commits + messages, so that I have a full history in the fork, of what changed in the parent.

So essentially, when you start a fork and you see the parent's entire commit history as the "starting point" for your fork, I would like to keep the parent's commit history ongoing in the fork, with my fork-specific commits interspersed (with conflict resolution as needed).

Is this possible?

Or if that's not possible, is there a way to script an automatic pull & merge of parent changes into the child fork, while coalescing the parent's commit messages into the new merge's commit message? (so all individual messages from imported commits, would be combined into one massive merge message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, mercurial and git share a lot in terms of data structures used for history and, in git at least, merging does just what you ask for. Just make sure that your merge commit (or changeset, as hg calls it) actually links to both parent commit (the mostrecent parent project commit and your fork's most recent commit), and that's it.

After merging, check upon the tree with, for example, hgk. It should look like:
http://wiki.genunix.org/wiki/images/3/3f/Screenshot-hgk.png

Comment: Looking at the visual flow, the process I used to merge indeed shows the deviation and then convergence in the code base, but the commit messages in the fork only reflect the fork-specific commits, without preserving the history from the parent. Using Bitbucket, it has a link in the message to each revision that was combined, but I'd like to see all messages intact in the actual revision log.

Comment: Bah, was just looking at it wrong. Imported commit history appears to be preserved, *in addition to* the new commit message due to the merge. Thanks :-)

Comment: Additionally, you can use `hg serve` and then look at http://localhost:8080/graph